# Installing dependencies in React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

If I downloaded a dependency using "npm install pkgname --save" but never used it will it slow my speed on production build react?

Comment: This depends on whatever you're using to build the react app. Also, are you asking about the speed of the app or the speed of the build process?

Comment: @richardpringle I am asking about the speed of the app. Thanks!

Comment: looks like you have your answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Webpack2+ won't bundle unused code on your final production build

Comment: Thank you! So Webpack2+ only includes the dependencies used in the production build.